# python airflow: create destination_dataset_table with cluster and partition?

Tags: python, airflow, google-bigquery

I use the airflow package in python. I am trying to create the destination dataset table with cluster and partition on specific fields.

```
cluster_fields = None
```

statement in this 
[link](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.html)

But I don't know how what to specify instead of "None".

Comment: Please elaborate your question and put it into a bit of context. It's quite unclear, what you are after.

Comment: i created a task in a DAG. this task runs a query and insert it in to destination table using WRITE_TRUNCATE. i want the destination table to be clustered using airflow package.

Comment: From the documentation it looks like this should be a list of column names (strings).  Is that not working for you?